# How to create a Rectangle Path when given start and end Rectangle

Tags: java, image-processing, path, collision-detection, rectangles

I'm checking for collisions between snooker balls using the Intersects call in the Rectangle class - each ball has a Rectangle which defines its hitbox.

How my code works is that I have rectangle representing the white ball's old position and a new one for its updated position. From here I need to check if there was a collision with another ball between the old position and the new position.

This is where I'm hoping for some assistance, what would be the best way to create a path / check if there's a possible collision between the old and new position?

Image representation

[image]

Comment: Can't you overlap current position image on to the last position image and then find if there was a collision or not ?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. I literally have two Rectangles - Old position rectangle and new position Rectangle. No other information other than the list of rectangles of the other balls. Trying to figure out how to move the old position rectangle along the path it takes checking each step if it collided with anything.

Answer (score 1):

To test if two circles have collided, you can compare the distance between the center of both circles to the sum of the radiuses. If the distance is smaller, they have collided.

For Rectangles, you can use Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle)

Comment: I'm aware of that - the collision itself isn't the issue. Trying to figure out how to get from the old position to the new position is the problem. If one frame you have the old position and the next frame you have the updated position I need to see if there was another ball in the path between the old and new position.